# Ant build.xml working Eclipse. Not working direct

Tags: eclipse, ant

My buildfile seems to be running correctly (and generating junit test reports) correctly when executing in Eclipse, however when I execute directly with: `ant -buildfile C:\....\build.xml` the files aren't produced - and the `cmd` output suggests it's not running the tests.

I have two eclipse projects. `JUnitTest1` which is the code. `JUnitTestUnitTests` which contains the test code.

I've followed the instructions [here](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/46598/) to create my buildfile in eclipse (selecting only the test project) and can see the files drop into the `junit` directory.

When I run `ant` command directly, no files are generated and it doesn't look like it's running my tests.

Why aren't the changes made via the eclipse GUI reflected in the build.xml? I thought it was auto updated?

[Here's the eclipse config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9neGx.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- WARNING: Eclipse auto-generated file.
          Any modifications will be overwritten.
          To include a user specific buildfile here, simply create one in the same
          directory with the processing instruction <?eclipse.ant.import?>
          as the first entry and export the buildfile again. --><project basedir="." default="build" name="JUnitTest1UnitTests">
<property environment="env"/>
<property name="ECLIPSE_HOME" value="../../../../../tools/eclipse-mars/"/>
<property name="junit.output.dir" value="junit"/>
<property name="JUnitTest1.location" value="../JUnitTest1"/>
<property name="debuglevel" value="source,lines,vars"/>
<property name="target" value="1.7"/>
<property name="source" value="1.7"/>
<path id="JUnitTest1.classpath">
    <pathelement location="${JUnitTest1.location}/bin"/>
    <pathelement location="${JUnitTest1.location}/../../../../../tools/libs/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${JUnitTest1.location}/../../../../../tools/libs/junit-4.12.jar"/>
</path>
<path id="JUnitTest1UnitTests.classpath">
    <pathelement location="bin"/>
    <pathelement location="../../../../../tools/libs/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="../../../../../tools/libs/junit-4.12.jar"/>
    <path refid="JUnitTest1.classpath"/>
</path>
<target name="init">
    <mkdir dir="bin"/>
    <copy includeemptydirs="false" todir="bin">
        <fileset dir="src">
            <exclude name="**/*.launch"/>
            <exclude name="**/*.java"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>
</target>
<target name="clean">
    <delete dir="bin"/>
</target>
<target depends="clean" name="cleanall">
    <ant antfile="build.xml" dir="${JUnitTest1.location}" inheritAll="false" target="clean"/>
</target>
<target depends="build-subprojects,build-project" name="build"/>
<target name="build-subprojects">
    <ant antfile="build.xml" dir="${JUnitTest1.location}" inheritAll="false" target="build-project">
        <propertyset>
            <propertyref name="build.compiler"/>
        </propertyset>
    </ant>
</target>
<target depends="init" name="build-project">
    <echo message="${ant.project.name}: ${ant.file}"/>
    <javac debug="true" debuglevel="${debuglevel}" destdir="bin" includeantruntime="false" source="${source}" target="${target}">
        <src path="src"/>
        <classpath refid="JUnitTest1UnitTests.classpath"/>
    </javac>
</target>
<target description="Build all projects which reference this project. Useful to propagate changes." name="build-refprojects"/>
<target description="copy Eclipse compiler jars to ant lib directory" name="init-eclipse-compiler">
    <copy todir="${ant.library.dir}">
        <fileset dir="${ECLIPSE_HOME}/plugins" includes="org.eclipse.jdt.core_*.jar"/>
    </copy>
    <unzip dest="${ant.library.dir}">
        <patternset includes="jdtCompilerAdapter.jar"/>
        <fileset dir="${ECLIPSE_HOME}/plugins" includes="org.eclipse.jdt.core_*.jar"/>
    </unzip>
</target>
<target description="compile project with Eclipse compiler" name="build-eclipse-compiler">
    <property name="build.compiler" value="org.eclipse.jdt.core.JDTCompilerAdapter"/>
    <antcall target="build"/>
</target>
<target name="JUnitTest1UnitTests">
    <mkdir dir="${junit.output.dir}"/>
    <junit fork="yes" printsummary="withOutAndErr">
        <formatter type="xml"/>
        <test name="com.me.tests.MyTestClass" todir="${junit.output.dir}"/>
        <classpath refid="JUnitTest1UnitTests.classpath"/>
    </junit>
</target>
<target name="junitreport">
    <junitreport todir="${junit.output.dir}">
        <fileset dir="${junit.output.dir}">
            <include name="TEST-*.xml"/>
        </fileset>
        <report format="frames" todir="${junit.output.dir}"/>
    </junitreport>
</target>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe I've fixed this.

Eclipse creates your build file and seperately, you configure your run configurations. These run configurations (where you specify the run order of the ant tasks) are **not** persisted or represented in the actual build file.

The default target of the build file is the target="build" ... So you need to manually edit the build file and use the depends="..." clause to chain together the dependancies of your tasks.

[This page](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/ant/ant-java-build-script-example.html) (read example build file and see final line) has a great explanation of the depends clause.